# Display post only index page and not create single pages for the posts

Tags: wordpress, post

I'm creating a one page website in Wordpress and I don't want the site to create single pages when I add a post.  I want to keep it to one page.  I have removed the link to the single pages so the visitor will just see one page but if you Google for the post it will show up on a single page and if u type the URL for it you will get there.  How can I remove this and keep the complete website to one page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a home.php that creates the home page the way you want it.
And create a index.php that does nothing but redirects to the home page.

```
<?php wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit; ?>
```

Remove the other php files.

Comment: I'm not really sure how you mean.. I have already designed my index.php. Can't add/take away some code in the loop.php to make this work?

Comment: Copy everything in index.php and put it in home.php. Remove everything from index.php and replace it with
<?php wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit; ?>

Comment: I can't get this to work. When do this i can still write the permalink in the browser and view the single post.. And when i log out i can't login again. When I try to do that wordpress says: "sorry, this file can't be edited" How do I fix this problem?